# How to set custom favicon in Laravel BackPack admin panel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, favicon, laravel-backpack

Does Laravel BackPack have easy way to set custom favicon in admin panel ? I would appreciate any help)

Comment: Have you tried adding a favicon.ico file to the root of the `public` directory?

Comment: Yeah, I did it and it works.I gGenerated a favicon here: http://realfavicongenerator.net/ and I added it in the master blade of the admin panel. Worked like a charm. Edit: I have a custom design

Comment: Indra, write please full path to file in which you append favicon link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve problem to add favicon link into my **layout.blade.php** file

> resources/views/vendor/backpack/base/layout.blade.php

! Do not forget to publish backpack views

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Backpack\Base\BaseServiceProvider
```

Great thanks to all who helped :)

Comment: Why is this needed? "php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Backpack\Base\BaseServiceProvider"